# Div overflow on top of window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div with tabs, each tab displaying different content. One of those tabs have a table higher than the screen size, once i open it, the div stretch and overflow from the top, out of the window. I have `overflow:auto` on the parent div, and the div stretch properly, but still a portion of the child div overflow from top.
On load, the child div is a small box centered in the screen, with the height depending on the content.

I use bootstrap to help.

```css
.parent
{
    background-image: url("images/CM3A2078.jpg");
    background-position: 20%;
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.child
{
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 250px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FF6400;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    min-width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.h-full
{
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-full">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-1 side h-full">
            <div class="purple-gradient-left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col h-full parent">
            <div class="child">
                <div>
                    Some content
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-disconnect">Deconnecter</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tab-display justify-content-end" role="tablist">
                                <li class="nav-item ">
                                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Administration</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Reservation</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Annulation</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                            <h3>HOME</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                            <h3>Reservation</h3>
                            <?php include 'traitement.php'; ReservationTable(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
                            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
                                laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-1 col-1 side h-full">
            <div class="purple-gradient-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And there is an image to show what happens.

[image]

Comment: share the full code that reproduce the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif here, i added everything.

Answer (score 0):

Add below styles to your CSS file.

```
* {
       box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.child 
  {
        max-height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: This time, the content overflow from the bottom, without stretching the div.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem by changing `position:absolute` to `position:sticky` in the child div.

Answer (score 0):

use `flex-wrap: wrap` on parent:

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Other options that can be useful:

```css
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
overflow: scroll;
```

Answer (score -1):

in .parent style add this:

```
height: 100%;
```

and add body style:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```